# bzr: ERROR: Branch "file:///C:/FolderName/BranchName/" appears to be bound to itself. Please use `bzr unbind` to fix

Tags: explorer, bazaar

```
Unable to use > bzr commit   command in the bazaar explorer as this error occurs ... bzr: ERROR: Branch "file:///C:/FolderName/BranchName/" appears to be bound to itself. Please use `bzr unbind` to fix. Tried using bzr unbind C:/FolderName/BranchName/ and  bzr bind C:/FolderName/BranchName/ . Still the  above error occurs.
```

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you apparently did was to use `bzr bind` by accident, which converted the branch to a checkout (also known as a "bound branch"). Checkouts/bound branches are used for centralized, CVS/SVN/Perforce-style version control, making it so that every commit is first applied to the master branch that the checkout is bound to.

In your case, the checkout is recursively bound to itself rather than a separate upstream branch, and Bazaar doesn't know what to do with that situation.

As the error message suggests, you can use `bzr unbind` to turn the checkout back into a regular branch again.

You can also use `bzr config` to check whether a branch is bound, and if so, to what upstream branch. A bound branch will have `bound=True` set and `bound_location` to the upstream branch.